# Showing only the external boundary of a GeoPandas DataFrame

Tags: geopandas

I have a GeoPandas DataFrame I collected from a shapefile. The shapefile is the Mexico City boundary from [here](https://www.inegi.org.mx/app/biblioteca/ficha.html?upc=889463526636)

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file(fname)
gdf.plot()
```

[image]

I would like to create a GeoPandas DataFrame with one row that contains only the external boundaries of such geometry.

Answer (score 5):

You need to merge all geometries to one. Because they seem to be adjacent, it will give you a single polygon.

```
polygon = gdf.geometry.unary_union
```

If you want it as gdf not shapely.geometry:

```
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon], crs=gdf.crs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
gdf.boundary.plot()
```